# netctl: Static IP configuration lost automatically after few seconds of starting the interface

Tags: arch-linux, hyper-v, static-ip

I am using netctl in Arch Linux on Hyper-V. I have two ethernet interfaces eth0 & eth1.

IP config:

1. eth0: dhcp (automatic configuration, no involvment of netctl)
2. eth1: static ip (10.10.10.1/8) using netctl profile
3. dhcpcd installed and enabled at startup
4. NetworkManager installed and enabled at startup

eth1 netctl profile (/etc/netctl/sth1static):

```
    Description='Static IP config for eth1'
Interface=eth1
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('10.10.10.1/8')
Gateway='10.10.10.2'
DNS=('10.10.10.2')
```

To start the interface I am doing as follows:

```
# netctl stop eth1static
# ip link set eth1 down
# # netctl start eth1static
# # netctl enable eth1static
```

After following the above steps, I am able to see the static IP configuration applied to the interface using 1ip a`. Also I am able to ping the guest interface from my host OS successfully. However after a minute or so, I see the interface lose its configuration and gets a` fe80:` based IPv6 address only and the ping stops working... Even after reboot, I don't see the IP configurtion on the interface, where as the other interface (eth0) is working fine.

Could anyone suggest what's going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Is there a device on the network already with this IP? That’s a rhetorical question. The point is, have you tested that theory.

Comment: There are total two devices in the network. i.e, Host OS configured to use static ip 10.10.10.2 (gateway for guest OS). Second us the guest OS, I am trying to set up static ip for. Also, when the interface on guest (Arch Linux) interface is active and the static IP is configured, ping is working, which stops when the configuration is lost or when the interface is brought down.

Comment: An easy enough test would be to set the IP to a completely different address. Try 10.10.10.203. If it works, it’s an IP conflict. In this case, when the interface is working on the other IP address, ping 10.10.10.1 and then cancel the ping and immediately type `arp -a` which will display if an arp entry exists for this IP address. Do this even if the ping fails. If an ARP entry exists then it means a device is responding on the network with that IP address and that is how a duplicate IP address is detected. There are logs to reveal this as well. But this is the simplest thing to try.